# Why C# is converting 0.75 to 1 when I store it to Int16

Tags: c#

My code is:

```
        double a = 0.6875;
        int[] b = new int[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            a = a * 2;
            b[i] = Convert.ToInt16(a);
            Console.Write(b[i]);// it print '1' instead of '0', 2nd time in the loop
            a = a - b[i];
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Why this is happening. I want '0' instead of '1' at that time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
b[i]=(int)(a)
```

instead of `Convert.To`

Answer (score 2):

[Convert.ToInt16](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s287dad5.aspx)

> Returns: value, rounded to the nearest 16-bit signed integer. If value is halfway between two whole numbers, the even number is returned; that is, 4.5 is converted to 4, and 5.5 is converted to 6.

Perhaps a cast would be more appropriate:

```
b[i] = (short)a;
```

Comment: What should I do to get '0' instead of '1'.

Comment: double a = 0.6875; 
        int[] b = new int[5]; 
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
        { 
            a = a * 2; 
            b[i] = Convert.ToInt16(a); 
            Console.Write(b[i]);// it print '1' instead of '0', 2nd time in the loop 
            a = a - b[i]; 
            Console.ReadKey(); 
        } 
What should I do to get '0' instead of '1'.

Comment: Replace the Convert.ToInt16 line with the cast, as described.

Answer (score 0):

It comes from the implementation of Convert : Convert does NOT cast, it tries to round the value you pass it to the closest one available in target type.
To perform what you want, you must use use int.TryParse or (int)a.

I'd suggest you read this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s287dad5.aspx

> " Type: System.Int16 value, rounded to
>   the nearest 16-bit signed integer. If
>   value is halfway between two whole
>   numbers, the even number is returned;
>   that is, 4.5 is converted to 4, and
>   5.5 is converted to 6."

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected result of the `Convert.ToInt16` method that you use to convert `a` to an `Integer` value stored in the `b` array.

From the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s287dad5.aspx) for this method:

> **Return Value**:
>
> System.Int16 value, rounded to
>   the nearest 16-bit signed integer. If
>   value is halfway between two whole
>   numbers, the even number is returned;
>   that is, 4.5 is converted to 4, and
>   5.5 is converted to 6.

If you want a finer level of control over how the rounding takes place, look into the [`Math.Round` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef48waz8.aspx). This allows you to specify the [mid-point rounding mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding.aspx) that is used:

> **ToEven** specifies that when a number is halfway between two others,
>   it is rounded toward the nearest even
>   number. (So 2.5 is rounded to 2).
>
> **AwayFromZero** specifies that when a number is halfway between two others,
>   it is rounded toward the nearest
>   number that is away from zero. (So 2.5
>   is rounded to 3).